# echo display $content

Tags: php, action, echo

Short example of my problem:

```
$myname = "Blah Blah";

$content = "<table><tr><td>".$myname."</td></tr></table>";

<?php
echo "<table><tr><td>".$myname."</td></tr></table><form name='makepdf' action='make_pdf.php?content=$content' method='POST'><button class='cupid-green' name='submitpdf'>Prenos PDF</button></form>";
?>
```

I will catch $content in make_pdf.php file later...

But the problem is that I get double display of $content where echo is presented. But if I change action='make_pdf.php?content=test' it works OK. I also catch $content in make_pdf.php.

I tried to make:

```
<input type='hidden' name='content' value='$content'>
```

I get similar or worse results because I don't catch $content = $_GET['content']; in make_pdf.php

Any solution?

Comment: try using isset to test if $_GET['content'] has a value set to it. if not, then you know it needs to be input.

Comment: You should probably POST that data not pass via GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in PHP

```
<?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='content' value='" . $content . "'>";
```

?>

in HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="content" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($content); ?>">
```

Comment: You were missing the `echo` in your second code snippet. Fixed it for you

Comment: Sorry i forgot about it! Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

Encode it using PHP's [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function:

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($content); ?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid `echo`-ing static HTML from PHP, it just complicates things.

You need to encode the markup for use in a `value` attribute using `htmlspecialchars()`. For example

```
?>

<input type="hidden" name="content" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($content) ?>">

<?php
```